# Yii2 REST+ Angular Cross Domain CORS

Tags: angularjs, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I have developed Angular & Yii2  REST service. Have problem in cross domain.
Here below add my angular & Yii2 REST Code.

AngularJs : (like 'http://organization1.example.com','http://organization2.example.com',....)

```
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + MYTOKEN
```

My Request from Angular Controller:

```
apiURL = 'http://api.example.com';
$http.get(apiURL + '/roles')
     .success(function (roles) { })
     .error(function () { });
```

Yii2 .htaccess: (REST URL like 'http://api.example.com')

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,X-Requested-With, content-type"
```

Yii2 My Behaviour:

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [
                'X-Pagination-Per-Page',
                'X-Pagination-Total-Count',
                'X-Pagination-Current-Page',
                'X-Pagination-Page-Count',
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'except' => ['options'],
    ];
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

**Problem**

From my angular request is 'GET' method, but it will goes 'OPTIONS' method & return 401 Unauthorized error(CORS). because the request Authorization header is not send.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**

As pointed by @jlapoutre, this is now well described [in official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors):

> Adding the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing filter to a controller is a
>   bit more complicated than adding other filters described above,
>   because the CORS filter has to be applied before authentication
>   methods and thus needs a slightly different approach compared to other
>   filters. Also authentication has to be disabled for the CORS Preflight
>   requests so that a browser can safely determine whether a request can
>   be made beforehand without the need for sending authentication
>   credentials. The following shows the code that is needed to add the
>   yii\filters\Cors filter to an existing controller that extends from
>   yii\rest\ActiveController:
>
> ```
> use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
>
> public function behaviors()
> {
>     $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
>
>     // remove authentication filter
>     $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
>     unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
>
>     // add CORS filter
>     $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
>         'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
>     ];
>
>     // re-add authentication filter
>     $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
>     // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
>     $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
>
>     return $behaviors;
> }
> ```

---

**Old Answer** *(deprecated)*

There is an ordering issue when merging with `parent::behaviors()`. Full details [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/11086#issue-140045955).

I would recommend not defining keys when merging with parent array:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge([
        [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [...],
        ],
        [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            'except' => ['options'],
        ],
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [...],
        ]
    ], parent::behaviors());
}
```

Comment: This is now documented clearly here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors - just follow this guide and it will work. Summary: make sure authentication comes after CORS behavior and exclude OPTIONS from authentication at all times.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
use yii\filters\Cors;
...
public function behaviors()
{
    return array_merge([
        'cors' => [
            'class' => Cors::className(),
            #special rules for particular action
            'actions' => [
                'your-action-name' => [
                    #web-servers which you alllow cross-domain access
                    'Origin' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST'],
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
                    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [],
                ]
            ],
            #common rules
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => [],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => [],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => [],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 0,
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [],
            ]
        ],
    ], parent::behaviors());
}
```

[Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-cors.html)

Answer (score 1):

issue with your code you are not unsetting auth at very start

```
public function behaviors() {
$behaviors = parent::behaviors();
/*unset here*/
unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
$behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
    'class' => Cors::className(),
    'cors' => [
        'Origin' => ['*'],
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [
            'X-Pagination-Per-Page',
            'X-Pagination-Total-Count',
            'X-Pagination-Current-Page',
            'X-Pagination-Page-Count',
        ],
    ],
];
/*re-set here*/
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    'except' => ['options'],
];
$behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
    'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
    'formats' => [
        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    ],
];

return $behaviors;
```

}