# Yii2 cors filters error that No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: php, angular, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Following [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359365/yii2-rest-angular-cross-domain-cors) i have set my rest controller behaviour as

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $auth= $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'only' => ['dashboard'],
    ];
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];
    $acces=$behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'only' => ['login'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
    unset($behaviors['access']);
```

And now the cors filters

```
    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
          'cors' => [
        // restrict access to
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'],
        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
        // Allow only POST and PUT methods
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
        // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
        // Allow OPTIONS caching
        'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
        // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [],
      ]
    ];

    // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
       $behaviors['access'] = $access;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

An my angular2 frontend as

```
    const body = JSON.stringify(user);
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "*");
return this._http.post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers:headers })
  .map((response: Response) => {
     //process response
  })
.catch(this.handleError);
```

But am still getting an error of

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What could be wrong since ive set the cors filter in yii2 behaviours unset authenticator and added it later
What could i be missing out

I have also checked on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646736/cors-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-no-acces) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)
 but none solves the issue

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Headers` is for the client side, server side should use `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: tried adding Access-control-allow-headers ['*'] but still fails to work

Comment: Try replacing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'], with 'Origin' => ['*'],

Comment: Thanks botis it now works, Another thing ive realized is on the return statement of the controller should be return not echo

Comment: I don't know what web-server you are using, but I think you have to set the CORS-Header in you web-server. Here is a description how to do that for apache: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: For that oliver ive added a .htaccess with enable headers and its stil works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case of any problems with CORS headers, I recommend to use following instruction:

1. Add cors configuration to your controller. For instance:

   ```
   /**
    * List of allowed domains.
    * Note: Restriction works only for AJAX (using CORS, is not secure).
    *
    * @return array List of domains, that can access to this API
    */
   public static function allowedDomains() {
       return [
           // '*',                        // star allows all domains
           'http://test1.example.com',
           'http://test2.example.com',
       ];
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function behaviors() {
       return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

           // For cross-domain AJAX request
           'corsFilter'  => [
               'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
               'cors'  => [
                   // restrict access to domains:
                   'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                   'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                   'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)
               ],
           ],

       ]);
   }
   ```
2. The above code will add **to response** special http-headers. Check http-headers using browser debug tools:
3. **Request http header** should contain `Origin`. It will be added by browser automatically at Crossdomain AJAX. This http-header can be added also via your JS library. Without this http-header `corsFilter` won't work.

   ```
   POST /api/some-method-name HTTP/1.1
   Host: api.example.com
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 86
   Accept: */*
   Origin: https://my-site.example.com
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   Referer: https://my-site.example.com/
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
   ```
4. **Response http headers** should contain `Access-Control-*` headers. This http-header will be added by `corsFilter`.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-site.example.com
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
   Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 09:21:47 GMT
   Server: Apache
   Content-Length: 27
   Connection: keep-alive
   ```
5. If you don't see these http headers **in response**, probably it means that `\yii\filters\Cors` doesn't work or conflicts with other filters.
6. Check other behaviors/filters in controller. Try add `corsFilter` as **first behavior**. Probably some other behaviors prevents execution of `corsFilter`.
7. Try **to disable CSRF validation** for this controller (it may prevent external access):

   ```
   /**
    * Controller for API methods.
    */
   class ApiController extends Controller
   {

       /**
        * @var bool See details {@link \yii\web\Controller::$enableCsrfValidation}.
        */
       public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

       // ...
   }
   ```
8. If you are using **authenticator** filter (for example, your controller extends `yii\rest\ActiveController`) the CORS filter has to be **applied BEFORE authentication methods**. Also authentication has to be **disabled for the CORS Preflight requests** so that a browser can safely determine whether a request can be made beforehand without the need for sending authentication credentials.

   ```
   use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

   public function behaviors()
   {
       $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

       // remove authentication filter
       $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
       unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

       // add CORS filter
       $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
           'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
       ];

       // re-add authentication filter
       $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
       // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
       $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

       return $behaviors;
   }
   ```
9. Additionally should be checked your web-server. Probably nginx may require additional configuration, apache can require **restarting**.
10. `Access-Control-*` headers in response can be added using web-server (see for [apache](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) and [nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)). But I don't recommend to use this way, because in this case you can't manage http-haders using application.
11. Some useful information can be found here:

    - [Yii2: How to allow CORS on non-restfull API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643344/yii2-how-to-allow-cors-on-non-restfull-api/39644477)

Comment: How would you deal with preflight requests with CORS filter configuration?

Comment: I have a case #5 (don't see these http headers in response) what should I do? I restarted nginx container, also tried adding headers using web-server (instruction #9) still no headers.

Comment: I fixed it by unsetting authenticator and resetting it back after cors, https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#cors

Comment: @temirbek Thanks! I've added your solution for **preflight requests** to the answer.

Comment: Took me a while but if you have custom routes in your main.conf add OPTIONS to your GET's and POST's

                'GET api2/settings/schema'              => 'api2/settings/schema',
                'POST api2/settings/write-bulk'         => 'api2/settings/write-bulk',
                'OPTIONS api2/settings/schema'              => 'api2/settings/schema',
                'OPTIONS api2/settings/write-bulk'         => 'api2/settings/write-bulk',

Answer (score 4):

Try This :

```
public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
        // '*',                        // star allows all domains
        'http://localhost:3000',
        'http://test2.example.com',
    ];
}  



public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

            // For cross-domain AJAX request
            'corsFilter'  => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                'cors'  => [
                    // restrict access to domains:
                    'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)

                ],
            ],

        ]);
    }
```

Add This Function on your controller  .

And One Thing angular2 use OPTION method at the first time For so allow OPTION method also

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises when the frontend runs in a port other than the default port (80).

Then in yii you need to specify the port to work. Example:
frontend runs at `http: // localhost: 3000`
in Yii cors set:

```
'Origin' => ['http: // localhost: 3000']
```

If you do not specify the port (3000), Yii interprets the port by default and the result is:

```
'Origin' => ['http: // localhost: 80']
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have answer for this and probably a fool proof one, though most of the things answered here are good, but nothing worked for me, unless I really understood the issue what is happening.

As some people correctly said, that browser tend to send options in pre-flight, so make sure each of your controller if customized are able to handle option request, if it is not you will keep wandering like me for ages, whats wrong, I have configured everything like what is described in documentations, implemented everything what everybody is saying over the net.

I am just giving you here few examples hope this will help, after implementing all the solutions mentioned above still nothing was working, unless I added a specific function to my controller actionOptions, something like this below

```
    public function actionOptions() {
    $header = header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}
```

and modified behaviours simply as described in Yii documentation

```
    public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    // remove authentication filter
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
    ];

    // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

And this worked like charm on my chrome browser.

Now, if you have some custome route set, like I had for one of my controller

Example:

> GET v1/users/profile
> You must set another route as OPTIONS v1/users/profile too.

Last but not the least, there could be some instances where one of your action is further customized or just just using standard action like in my case actionIndex

I added the header specifically as following on the top in that action like below for actionIndex

```
  public function actionProfile() {
    $header = header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $profile = new \app\modules\v1\models\Profile();
    return $profile->prepare();
}

  public function actionIndex() {
    $header = header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $profile = new \app\modules\v1\models\Profile();
    return $profile->prepare();
}
```

I hope this will help some of you :).

Comment: + for OPTIONS in routes, that could be done via 'GET,OPTIONS v1/users/profile' => 'site/index'

Answer (score 0):

It is important to write $behaviors['access'] ie. AccessControl as a last parameter, for example:

```
public function behaviors()     {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors(); 

    // remove authentication filter         
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);   

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [     
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
        'cors'  => [
                'Origin' => ['*'], 
                'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'], 
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'accept', 'Authorization'], 
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],    
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600, // Cache (seconds) 
                // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.             
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Total-Count', 'X-Pagination-Page-Count', 'X-Pagination-Current-Page', 'X-Pagination-Per-Page'] 
        ] 
    ];           

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [ ... whatever ... ];          

    $behaviors['access'] = [           
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),           
      'rules' => [   
                  [  
                    'allow' => true,   
                    'actions' => ['options'], // important for cors ie. pre-flight requests   
                  ], 
                ]   
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

my fix is :

```
   // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => Cors::class,
    ];

    // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    //$behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['index', 'refresh-products'];
```

also I have config as:
mentioning the controller name in UrlManger

```
     'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        // 'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,

        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'pluralize' => false,
                'controller' => [
                    'v1/setting',
                    'v1/restaurant',
                                       ],
                'ruleConfig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlRule',
                ],
            ],
            'v1/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/view',
            'v1/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
            'v1/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
            'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/view',
            'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
            'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:\w+>' => 'v1/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```