# angular6:Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angular6, yii2-advanced-app

Using back end yii2 advanced framework, calling api request using POST method getting the error as: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
const BASE_API_URL = 'http://localhost/harshini/kpa/backend/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
};
sendValue(message: Kpa) {
    return this.http.put(BASE_API_URL, message, httpOptions);
  }
```

[image]
Here am adding image please help.

Comment: Please any one help me solve this issue,i stuck in this problem from past four days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `cors` issue,

Enable `cors` from server side. 
Please refer this link [Yii2 cors filters error that No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647444/yii2-cors-filters-error-that-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: i already enabled cors in server side,but still am getting same error.@AmolBJamkar

Comment: Your image shows that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not present in preflight call response, means you need to add it `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` or enable cors to handle that. check your options call again.