# How can I use CORS filter in Yii 1.1 in ApiController?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, cors, yii1.x

Using it in 2.0 is very simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435000 8 https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters#core-filters 12 but I cannot find instruction how to use it Yii 1.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try following the instructions for 2.0 just to see if it works? Did you attempt any solution? Please provide us some more details on your research.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your controller's `afterAction` with setting additional headers

```php
class MyController extends CController
{
    public function afterAction($action) {
        Yii::app()->cors->set();

        parent::afterAction($action);
    }
}
```