# Yii2 Select2 Lazy loading resulting in 403 when searching

Tags: ajax, yii2, lazy-loading, jquery-select2, http-status-code-403

I have used select2 in YII2 and used lazy loading for it, everything works fine, but many times when user is typing with speed, some of the request are resulting in 403, user has to wait for some seconds before it starts working again,another observation is, we have two instances exactly running the same code, one instance works without this issue and another one has this issue. We checked setup for both and they are exactly same. So not sure what is happening and why it is happening. Any suggestions pointers to check?

Comment: add `minimumInputLength` property to avoid consecutive requests on type.

Comment: That will surely reduce the occurance but won't completely eliminate the issue

Comment: Tried this link suggestions as well, no positive effect though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647444/yii2-cors-filters-error-that-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: You can set [delay](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#rate-limiting-requests) property to avoid multiple request.

Comment: Ok are you suggesting in ajax?

Comment: Yes, add the code of your select2.

Comment: OK will try that one as well, but still I guess these are band aids right? In the first place it should not give me 403 if I am doing everything as per requirement for security

Comment: Not band aids, these options are documented as well, 403 is your security issue, check what's wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Yes 403 is security issue, as I said in my question above, the server on which it is giving this is exact replica of another server running and does not have this issue at all. We are checking that part as well to see if there is any difference in the server settings. I have added all these points in the system and as I said they have reduce the occurances, but I am trying to find out the root cause of it so as to eliminate it completely.